# Why did the animals die?

Tags: constantine

In constantine, the guy that found the spear of destiny jumps over a fence. The camera pans around and there is a field of animals. As he walks through the field along the path, the animals die.

Why did this happen?

Comment: I always took it that the Spear was sucking the life out of them, but that is just conjecture on my part.

Comment: The Spear of Destiny was supposedly the spear used by a Roman soldier to verify that Christ was indeed dead on the cross. When the soldier stabbed the spearhead into Christ's abdomen, blood and water flowed out. This could be interpreted as the spear taking the life-giving essences from Christ. The spear shown in Constantine is representative of one of the spears known to exist. It was recast/reshaped with a nail that was used to crucify Christ in the spearhead. In the movie, it appears the director intended to show the Spear sucking the life essences out of the animals as well.

Comment: @CGCampbell In the movie, the Spear is what killed Jesus (*Jesus didn't die from being nailed to a cross. He was killed by a soldier's spear.*).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have my DVD with me, so I cannot check, but if I remember right, this was not addressed in the movie.

When that scene takes place, we only know that the thing (that we later  learn is the Spear) is something (possibly a relic, given the type of the movie) that was wrapped in the Nazi flag and that possessed Manuel, immediately killing him but keeping him "alive", and setting him on some mission. So, I think that the movie wants to add an ominous feeling to this - at the moment unexplained - sequence of events.

We can easily argue that the Spear is not deadly in itself, but rather affected or manipulated by something or someone (as is later indirectly confirmed). Had it been deadly, neither Manuel nor his friend would get close to it. Instead, they'd just drop like the cattle you're asking about.

The Spear also didn't kill Constantine and Chas when they were in the same room with it, giving me further reason to consider the death of the cattle just a means of building the suspension, and not something deeper.

One could argue that it only killed animals, but - again - no explanations nor in-movie reasons for that are ever given.